# Using "+" as String in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I am trying to make a ONP transformer in swift, so I made a map String->Int for operators:

- ops["+"] = 1
- ops["-"] = 1
- ops["*"] = 2
- ops["/"] = 2

Unfortunetely, when i try to call ops["+"] i got nil. Debuger says   "unable to read data" for "+" and "-" as keys. "*" and "/" works fine.
Is there any special character to input before + - to make it use as String?

Edit.

```
class ONP {


    let equation:String?
    var stack = [String]()
    var knownOperators = [String:Int]()

    init(equation: String?){
        self.equation = equation
        initOperators()
    }

    func initOperators(){
        knownOperators["+"] = 1
        knownOperators["−"] = 1
        knownOperators["×"] = 2
        knownOperators["/"] = 3
    }

    func transform() -> [String]?
    {
        var result = [String]()
        if let sequence = splitEquation(){
            for op in sequence{
                if let operatorPriority = knownOperators[op]
                {
                    while( !stack.isEmpty && (operatorPriority <= knownOperators[stack.last!]))
                    {
                        result.append(stack.removeLast())
                    }
                    stack.append(op)

                }
                else {
                    result.append(op)
                }

            }
            while !stack.isEmpty {
                result.append(stack.removeLast())
            }
            return result
        }
        return nil
    }

    private func splitEquation() -> [String]?
    {
        return equation?.characters.split(" ").map(String.init)
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you include the code so we can see exactly how this is declared? You can [edit] your post. Copy-paste your code, select it, and press Ctrl+K.

Comment: Your `+` looks like a standard ASCII plus, but your `-` has a unicode value of 8722 instead of the expected 45.  Make sure you are using the characters you expect since there are multiple characters that look like `-`.

Comment: you don't need `initOperators`, you could just define your operators as a map literal off the bat.

Comment: Maybe a stupid comment, but this is supposed to transform a string into a math expression ? if yes then I hope you know NSExpression... But as I said : this is maybe a stupid comment.

Answer (score 1):

I have copied your code into playground and called:

```
let onp = ONP(equation: "3 + 4 * 2")
onp.knownOperators["+"] // 1
onp.knownOperators["−"] // 1
onp.knownOperators["×"] // 2
onp.knownOperators["/"] // 3
```

As you can see, I get correct values, make sure that your use the exact same characters, with the same unicode value. You can check with something like:

```
extension Character {
    var unicodeScalarsValue: UInt32 {
        return String(self).unicodeScalars.first!.value
    }
}
Character("-").unicodeScalarsValue //normal minus = 45
Character("−").unicodeScalarsValue //your minus = 8722
```

Comment: yes you are right, I was using different values. But still i got [link](http://imgur.com/23U4POm) in debuger

Comment: @JarosławKrajewski if I do `print(onp.knownOperators)` I get `["×": 2, "+": 1, "/": 3, "−": 1]`. How do you call your class and show your operators? (please don't rely on the debugger preview, sometimes it may not show some values)

Comment: In this case my program works, but I ma wondering why debugger says that is unable to read data only when key is "+".

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful when using special characters within your source code. Other developers may not be aware of it. For example, the multiply sign look like the lowercase `x` to me. You may also forget a few months later what exact characters you used so you have to switch a lot back and forth for copy-and-paste.

It's better to define them as constants:

```
enum KnownOperator: String {
    case Plus = "+"        // U+2B
    case Minus = "−"       // U+2212
    case Multiply = "×"    // U+D7
    case Divide = "/"      // U+2F
}

let knownOperators: [KnownOperator: Int] = [.Plus: 1, .Minus: 1, .Multiply: 2, .Divide: 2]
```